# Detecting symmetries in polynomials that lead to nice geometric properties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, symmetric-groups

If we plot the single variable polynomial $p(x) = (x^2-1)^2$, it is easy to see that it has a nice property: all of its local minima are actually global minima.

[image]

In particular, it has precisely two local minima due to symmetry the $x\to -x$, and all of them have the same globally optimal function value. In fact, for this simple example, if we have $p(x) = (x^2+x^n-1)^2$ where $n$ is even, then we will see that this nice property still holds.  Proving such a property directly (that all local min and global min) is easy in the single variable case. You can basically just check all the critical points.

However, for multivariable polynomials this property seems more difficult to check. For instance, consider $p(x,y) = (x^2-1)^2+4x^2y^2+y^4$. It is again easy to see from the graph that it has exactly the same property: all local minima are also global minima. In this case you can still prove it directly by computing the gradient and the Hessian. However, for more variables this process becomes tedious.

[image]

My question is simple. Is there a general way to check these kind of properties purely using symmetries of the polynomial itself?  I would appreciate some pointers to results in this direction since I do not have a deep background in algebraic geometry.

Comment: Well, if the symmetry group acts transitively on the local minima, then they all have the same value which must be the global minimum. That's true for all the examples you gave but I assume you want something more than that?

Comment: I am curious about that too. +1